Can GraphSAGE be applied to characterize vrp data?
My scene is as follows:
(1) Suppose there are 10000 vrp graph, each graph contains 100 nodes and each node is featured by its coordinates, i.e. (x,y)
(2) My goal is to use these data to train a GraphSAGE in a self-supervised manner. When encountering unseen graph, trained GraphSAGE can generate node embedding for the graph, the output node embedding is used for downstream tasks, i.e. solving VRP using Reinforcement learning.
(3) My question is does GraphSAGE apply to the scenario?
Welcome to share and learn together, thanks!
